# How to handle `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, try-catch

I have `await` statements which can throw errors so I am executing them inside a `try/catch`. However the `try/catch` is not catching them I get warnings:

> (node:4496) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Request timed
>   out.

My code is:

```
(async() => {
try
{
    const result_node = nodeClient.getInfo();

}
catch (e)
{
    console.error("Error connecting to node: " + e.stack);
}
})();
```

I have also tried using `wait-to-js`. Although it catches the error I still get the error in stderr.

```
(async() => {
try
{
    const [err_node, result_node] = await to(nodeClient.getInfo());
        if(err_node)
            console.error("Could not connect to the Node");
}
catch (e)
{
    console.error("Error connecting to node: " + e.stack);
}
})();
```

What is the right way to handle errors with `async/await`?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `await` keyword when you are waiting for an async call to return.

```
(async() => {
  try
  {
    const result_node = await nodeClient.getInfo(); // <- await keyword before the function call
  }
  catch (e)
  {
    console.error("Error connecting to node: " + e.stack);
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
(async() => {
   try{
       const result_node = await nodeClient.getInfo();
   }catch (e){
       console.error("Error connecting to node: " + e.stack);
   }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

correct process to use async await is

```
var functionName = async() => {
    try
    {
        const result_node = await nodeClient.getInfo();
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        console.error("Error connecting to node: " + e);
    }
}
```